# What screenshot do i need to submission to appstore

Tags: ios, screenshot, submission

I want to make sure what screenshot need to be uploaded.

Do i only need to upload the 12.9inch display only and apple will apply to all other devices? or do i need to upload for specific devices.

How many screenshot is required to upload.

Comment: iTunes Connect (App Store Connect) shows you what screenshots are required.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upload at least two types of screenshots
The first is 12.9 inches and the second is 5.5 inches.
It is recommended to upload 5 screenshots per type to fully reflect the functions of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Aapple will apply to all other devices. You must upload at least one screenshot of your app.
For iPad, screenshots for 12.9-inch iPad Pro (2nd generation) and 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation) are required. These screenshots will scale down for smaller device sizes.
You can read more information below link :

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev910472ff2

Comment: does that mean i don't need phone device

Comment: Screenshots 12.9-inch using for iPad, It not include iPhone.